# How to re enable a deleted windows 10 user account?

Tags: windows-10

I accidentally deleted my user account from the user account settings in control panel but chose "keep my files" option. So my user folder is still there. Can it therefore be re enabled so that i an get all my desktop layout and applications as it was before ?

Comment: I guess not. You would have to create a new account and copy that files to the new account.

Answer (score 0):

Some online articles such as https://www.easeus.com/file-recovery/recover-deleted-user-profile-and-files-in-windows-10.html has suggested some ways by using:

1. Recovery Software (This is for copying the files from the deleted user account to a newly created account which is not your primary option and can be done manually also).
2. Registry Modification (I would not suggest this as modifying the registry incorrectly can cause more damage to the system).
3. System Restore (Elaborated below).

System Restore may only end up restoring the folder of the User Account rather than the actual account where you can login but we can at least try some steps.

Before doing any of these
I would suggest you to perform a System Restore by searching **Create a restore point** and then followed by **Create** and proceed to Create a Restore Point.

Once you created that restore point, you can proceed by selecting **System Restore**.
If you are presented with a **Recommended Restore**, do not select that, select **Choose a different restore point**.
From here, you may be presented with no restore points (which then this method doesn't apply and you will have to manually migrate everything to the new account) or at least one or more restore points. Select a restore point which is dated **BEFORE** the deletion of the account and let Windows perform the system restore which may take a while.

There is also a user which also suggested a System Restore and you can refer to this post in the link below:
https://superuser.com/a/1060345/1231460

In terms of desktop layouts (and probably customization) and programs or applications, I myself have not tried System Restore to recover deleted account or corrupted account, rather I created a new user account and move important files to the new user account (since you have chosen to "keep my files"), manually install back applications and customize everything again which do take time but I would like to hear back if the System Restore actually does work for you and how does it look like after performing a System Restore if it only restores the folder which goes back to the original problem or it actually restores the whole user account where you can actually log back in